# Circular progressbar around an image

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, upload, progress-bar

I am trying to design an intuitive avatar upload on my site. The avatars are being resized to 150x150. Since I don't want to clobber my form too much, I was thinking of providing an upload button and a spot to show the current avatar as a preview image. Once the user clicks the button, he can choose a new avatar and once its clicked, the upload is processed. But during the process, I want to tell the user if anything is happening at all.

I have gone through a variety of jQuery plugins but I have not found a single one that is both cross-browser compatible or even allows custom HTML content within the drawn shapes.

My setup is Bootstrap 3 and jQuery 1.11.1. My upload is done using either `delivery.js` - file transmission over Socket.io - or plain AJAX to a PHP page since both can return progress information.

Does anyone of you know of a library that can draw a progress indicator around a container, or a way to implement it? Bootstrap has `ing-circle` to make the thumbnail a circle already. All I want is to draw some bar around it to indicate that stuff is going on.

Comment: Did you find any answer for this? Actually i also need something like this. Want to show circular progress bar around an image. Please help me.

Comment: @SoniaSarangal Yeah I did. [progressbar.js](https://github.com/kimmobrunfeldt/progressbar.js/issues/64) can do it. I linked an issue ticket where I asked. It has examples too.